# Can we show a popup to the user when user shakes his phone without opening the application in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process

Required: User will open and interact with our app and then switches to other app as usual. Now whenever, he shakes up the iPhone, we want to detect this event and show a popup to the user and send location information to our servers.

- How can we achieve this in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

No. Accessing the gyroscope is not part of the available background processing modes.